# Set the headers for authorization api

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am passing the headers from the response of login API to the next authorized API.

Test plan structure:
[image]

I have to pass the SRToken, Id1, Id2, and Id3 in the header so, I have added JSON extractor for all these headers and set the values fro them. Below screenshot shows how I have extracted values. Example 
[image]

In this way I have extracted values fro Id1, Id2 and Id3.
Then I have used Debug Sampler to view the values are stored?
But I am not getting the values here. 
[image]

I have also tried using Regular Expression Extractor
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract based on Response Header field. Use Regular Expression extractor as a child of your Login Sampler [from whose response these fields need to be extracted]. Sample Regular Expression is shown where I am extracting digit [change Regular Expression to (\w+) if you want to extract words. or any regex will work].

Most important here is to select "Field to check as Response Headers"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JSON is irrelevant in Headers,

You should use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with `Field to check` set `Request Headers` and use regular expression for getting the needed values

Comment: I have also tried using Regular Expression Extractor, but not getting the value. Could you please explain to me with example?

Comment: @vijayateke regex as `SRToken: (\w+)`

Comment: I have edited my question with how I have tried with Regular Expression Extractor. Please let me know where I am wrong

Comment: @vijayateke You didn't choose Field to check set Request Headers

Comment: How to choose the field and where?

Comment: @vijayateke It's a radio button in Regular Expression Extractor