# How to pass the response header to authorized api using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am using Regular Expression Extractor for extracting the header values.
Here is my test plan structure.
[image]

I am getting a response in login api is 
[image]

I want to extract the SRToke, Id1, Id2 and Id3 values from above response header. So I have used Regular Expression Extractor as below
[image]

I have also used BeanShell PostProcessor
[image]

Now I am getting the error 401 in result 
[image]

Please give me the solution, what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the variables from Response Header section of your Login request. Please refer how to capture from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391175/4481179

After extracting, use HTTP Header Manager as a child of Eventlist Sampler and pass that extracted value as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get an error about 401 because you did not add authorized success. You need to know the flow of the system. Maybe its need another parameter beside one parameter BEARER like you.

Answer (score -1):

I think Beanshell won't be required as you are not correlating from cookies, try to find the missing header under the 401 transaction something like Authorization and place the correlated variable there.